# AWS CLI : security group ID

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, command-line-interface, amazon-iam, aws-cli

I want to access the security group id. This is the command I used to create it, can anyone provide a one line command to view this table again?

```
aws --profile awscli-user-1 \
    ec2 create-security-group \
    --group-name ssh-access \
    --description "Security group for SSH access" \
    --vpc-id vpc-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \
    --output table
```

This is what I got after creating it

```
-------------------------------------
| CreateSecurityGroup               |
+----------+------------------------+
| GroupId  | sg-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX    |
+----------+------------------------+
```

How can I view this again?

Comment: Use some variant of `aws ec2 describe-security-groups --group-ids sg-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`.